# In the Jira Python API, how can I get a list of all labels used in a project?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I am using the python API for Jira.  I would like to get a list of all the labels that are being used in a project.  I know that issue.fields.labels will get me just the labels of an issue, but I am interested in looping through all the labels used in a project.  Found this to list all components in a project
components = jira.project_components(projectID)

Am looking for something similar, but for labels...

Comment: Looks like the Jira Python library does not provide this, but you might be able to [use the REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63496223/4288506).

Answer (score 3):

Using jira-python library for python3

For a whole project, you would write a loop to iterate through the issues in the project, then append the labels to a list.

```
from jira import JIRA
host = "http://<site>.atlassian.net"
jira = JIRA(host,basic_auth=(<user>, <password>))

projectlist = jira.search_issues('project = "Project Name"')
alllabels = []
for ticket in projectlist:
    issue = jira.issue(ticket)
    labels = issue.fields.labels
    for i in labels:
        alllabels.append(i)
```

If you wanted unique labels only you could use a set instead of a list for alllables.

Comment: Sad that we must resort to this. Thanks

Comment: Optimization hints: Use a `set` instead of `list` to have unique entries (`alllabels = set()`). Also, update the set with `alllabels.update(labels)` instead of iterating through all retrieved `labels`.

Answer (score 2):

Labels are a field that is shared across all issues potentially, but I don't think there is a REST API to get the list of all labels. So you'd either have to write a JIRA add-on to provide such a resource, or retrieve all the issues in question and iterate over them. You can simplify things by excluding issues that have no label

JQL: project = MYPROJ and labels is not empty

And restrict the fields that are returned from the search using the "fields" parameter for search_issues