# Does the JIRA REST API support querying a list of labels?

Tags: label, jira, jira-rest-api

I see the is the ability to get all components of a project by doing

```
/project/[projectkey]/components
```

but I don't see any capability or documentation on how to get the list of labels that are available for a project (something like:

```
/project/[projectkey]/labels
```

Does the JIRA REST API support querying the list of labels available on a project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify, labels (at least the built-in JIRA ones) are global entities so they can be attached to any Issue in any Project.

As to your question - no, there's no public REST endpoint to get/change/add labels to JIRA.

Answer (score 2):

Jira Cloud has [`/rest/api/3/label`](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-labels/#api-rest-api-3-label-get).

Jira Server provides [`/rest/api/2/jql/autocompletedata/suggestions?fieldName=labels`](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/8.10.1/#api/2/jql/autocompletedata-getFieldAutoCompleteForQueryString) which is however not paginated and only returns the first few labels (label values can be queried using `&fieldValue=X`).

However, as hacky workaround you can misuse the API endpoints some Atlassian Jira Gadgets are communicating with. Though this has the following disadvantages:

- Are internal APIs
- Atlassian apparently plans to replace Gadgets with Dashboard Items [eventually](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/building-a-dashboard-item/)
- Might change behavior, see e.g. [JRASERVER-67446](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-67446)
- No pagination (?), responses can be huge
- Responses are designed for Gadgets, therefore contain irrelevant data

#### Labels Gadget

`/rest/gadget/1.0/labels/gadget/project-<PROJECT_ID>/labels`
Where `<PROJECT_ID>` is the numeric ID of the project.

#### Heat Map Gadget

`/rest/gadget/1.0/heatmap/generate?projectOrFilterId=<PROJECT_OR_FILTER>&statType=labels`
Where `<PROJECT_OR_FILTER>` can be either:

- `project-<PROJECT_ID>`
- `filter-<FILTER_ID>`